# Dom parser to parse xml

Tags: java, dom

Getting an issue to parse the xml using DOM,using the approach as defined in http://www.developerfusion.com/code/2064/a-simple-way-to-read-an-xml-file-in-java/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<apis xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
    <api name="getFormFields" requesttype ="GET">
         <url>/fieldtype/</url>       
         <parameters>
             <parameter><![CDATA[fieldtype=textbox&fieldId=8668376496495]]></parameter>

          </parameters>
 </api>
```

Comment: also add any exception you are getting...

Comment: why SAX? use DOM parsing

Comment: @vishalrmakwana you should also mention the error message.

Comment: XML as posted appears valid. Looks like a problem with your SAX program.

Comment: not able to read name,request type

Comment: not a good question as it stands, we don't have the time nor the inclination to read too much linked material to sort your problem out. Distil your problem to a specific question, then you may get more help. (you can edit your own question and add more information - not comments)

Comment: (1) Please edit your question and put the additional stuff from your comments into it - that way you can format it better; (2) Please show your code: what have tried, where in the code do you think the issue is?

Comment: @ Nim,@ Aleks ,i have edited it ,i have tried the same code as specified in the link,not sure how to read name and request type params

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is you use JAXB standard, benefit of using jaxb are:

1. It is standard.
2. It is simple for use.
3. Support  Marshal and Unmarshal together.
4. It is newest version of XML Processing in java and released after JAXP

You can find good tutorial in here:

1. http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjaxb.java.net%2Ftutorial%2F&ei=E9cwT5GlI4aR-wau7OTpBQ&usg=AFQjCNGP2lvdm22FIL5JJO3exd9m067O6g&sig2=G07GhxXn_6tMfyTCr_fGDg
2. http://www.vogella.de/articles/JAXB/article.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html) which contain step by step documentation.

Here's an example XML file:

```
<bank>
    <customer id="1">
        <first>John</first>
        <last>Smith</last>
        <address>1 Broadway, San Fransico, CA</address>
        <balance>3230</balance>
    </customer>
    <customer id="2">
        <first>Bill</first>
        <last>Gates</last>
        <address>555 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA</address>
        <balance>9876543</balance>
    </customer>
</bank>
```

And the code to parse it:

```
public class BankTest {

    final StackContentHandler handler = new StackContentHandler();
    final Bank bank = new Bank();

    public BankTest() {
        handler.setElementHandler("bank", "customer", new CustomerHandler());
        handler.connect("customer","first", "customer.firstName");
        handler.connect("customer","last", "customer.lastName");
        handler.connect("customer","address", "customer.address");
        handler.connect("customer","balance", "customer.balance");

        try {
            SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
            parser.parse(new File("d:\\mybank.xml"), handler);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class CustomerHandler extends ElementAdapter {
        private Customer customer;

        public void startElement(ElementHandler parent, String element, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            customer = new Customer();
            customer.setId(Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue("id")));
            bank.addCustomer(customer);
        }

        public Customer getCustomer() {
            return customer;
        }
    }
}
```

for more info use the [link](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t104100.html)

Comment: true, it would be great if anyone shares the sample snippet for the above xml

Answer (score 0):

U can use Xstream to parse the XML to the java objects it is simple and easy to learn.
Here is the [Xstream Tutorial](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html)

Comment: @ Nivesh xstream looks a better approach ,but how to handle things like <person name="shell"> ,how to set name?

Comment: please help to resolve this Dom parser to parse xml question posted in stackoverflow